# Hive INSTR function working incorrectly on string with UTF8 characters

Tags: hadoop, hive, utf

Hive INSTR function is working incorrectly on strings with UTF8 characters. When an accent character is part of the string, INSTR returns an incorrect character location for subsequent characters. It seems to be counting bytes instead of characters.

With the accent character as part of string it returns 8

```
select INSTR("Réservation:", 'a'); returns 8
```

Without the accent character as part of string it returns 7

```
select INSTR("Reservation:", 'a'); returns 7
```

Is there a fix to this or an alternate function that I could use ?

Answer (score 3):

This what I'm getting with hive 1.1.0,

```
hive>select INSTR("Réservation:", 'a');
OK
7
```

So no issues with Hive. If you still need problem with using `INSTR` write your own UDF to achieve this. For writing UDF refer the below link,

[Click here for UDF](http://www.hadooplessons.info/2014/12/user-defined-functions-in-hive.html)